# Restrict search results in google places api by particular area or state in a country, react native (Javascript)

Tags: react-native, google-api, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am using Google Places API in my react native app and I want to filter or restrict search results.

**I want to restrict the search results to the Mumbai region or a particular state (only Kerala). How can I do it?**

*code I used in my project.*

```
 const url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=' 
  + Address +'&key=' + YOUR_API_KEY +'&types=(point_of_interest,establishment)&language=en&country=IN'

  fetch(url)
    .then(res => {
      return res.json()
    })
    .then(res => {
      if(res.results.length > 0){
        setLocationResults(res.results)
      }else{
        setLocationResults([])
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("ERR :",error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve this as Google's Places API does not understand such segregations is to pass the `location` and `radius` params. You just set the `location` to the center of the state/region and then set a sufficient `radius` which will cover the whole region.

You can check out the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#radius)